# Closure error when converting code from swift 2

Tags: swift, swift3, closures

I have the following code where i make a request for activation with some parameters

```
        /*
    Make an API request for activation
    */
    var parameters: [String : AnyObject] =
    [
        "code" : code as AnyObject,
        "dob" : httpClient.dateOfBirthFormatter.string(from: dateOfBirth) as AnyObject,
        "csr" : CSR as AnyObject,
        "deviceType" : systemVersion as AnyObject,
        "deviceModel" : deviceInfo as AnyObject
    ]
    if let deviceId = deviceId {
        parameters["deviceId"] = deviceId as AnyObject?
    }

    httpClient.devicePOST("api/activation", parameters: parameters as AnyObject?, handleAuthorization: false, start: nil, retry: nil,

        success:
        {
            (task: URLSessionDataTask, result: AnyObject?) -> Void in

            guard let response = result as? [String : AnyObject] else {
                failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: ["reason" : "Invalid response"]))//change this later
                return
            }

            guard let certificatePEM = response["certificate"] as? String else {
                failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: ["reason" : "Invalid response: certificate"]))//change this later
                return
            }

            /*
            Data is valid, activation is successful. Retrieve optional device identifier and call success handler
            */
            var deviceId: UUID?
            if let identifier = response["id"] as? String {
                deviceId = UUID(uuidString: identifier)
            }

            success(certificatePEM, customerId, patientId, deviceId)
        },

        failure: {

            (task: URLSessionDataTask?, error: NSError) -> Void in

            if let data = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as? Data {
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
                    print(string)
                }
            }

            failure(error)
        }
    )
}
```

The device POST function is defined as below

```
typealias StartSessionTaskHandler = (URLSessionDataTask) -> Void
typealias RetrySessionTaskHandler = (URLSessionDataTask) -> Void
typealias SuccessResponseHandler = ( URLSessionDataTask, AnyObject?) -> Void
typealias FailureResponseHandler = (URLSessionDataTask?, NSError) -> Void


func devicePOST(_ URLString: String, parameters: AnyObject?, handleAuthorization: Bool = true, start: StartSessionTaskHandler?, retry: RetrySessionTaskHandler?, success: SuccessResponseHandler?, failure: FailureResponseHandler?) {

    guard let deviceService = deviceService else {

        failure?(nil, NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: ["reason": "device service is unavailable"]))
        return
    }

    POST(deviceService, URLString: URLString, parameters: parameters, handleAuthorization: handleAuthorization, start: start, retry: retry, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

In the POST function when i try to inspect the closure blocks i see something like this

[image: POST function closure description]

[image: Success closure description]

So the blocks are not passed correctly i guess. This was working fine when i used swift 2. Can some one help me out on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by defining the block for failure and success.

I defined the success closure as

```
  success : {
        (task:URLSessionDataTask,object: Any?) -> Void in
         success(task,object)
    }, failure: failure)
```

And this is generally what i followed to pass the data back in the stack